# Why vitamin D3 is deficient in children and the elderly?

Tags: nutrition, vitamin-d

Vitamin D 3 of the most important vitamins that contribute to the growth of the human body.
  Why this vitamin is deficient and few in children and the elderly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vitamin D is not strictly a vitamin, rather it is the precursor of one
>   of the hormones involved in the maintenance of calcium homeostasis and
>   the regulation of cell proliferation and differentiation, where it has
>   both endocrine and paracrine actions.

It is important to note that the most important source is the endogenous synthesis in the skin by **photolysis** of 7-dehydrocholesterol compared to dietary sources;
problems of deficiency arise when there is **inadequate exposure to sunlight**.

> Two compounds have the biological activity of vitamin D:
>   cholecalciferol, which is the compound formed in the skin, and
>   ergocalciferol, which is synthesized by ultraviolet (UV) irradiation
>   of ergosterol

There are few foods that are rich sources of vitamin D. It is generally accepted that, for people with inadequate exposure
to sunlight (young children and the house-bound elderly), supplements are
necessary to maintain adequate status.

Unfortunately, dietary sources of vitamin D are few, and most foodstuffs
are devoid of vitamin D. The only significant sources of
vitamin D (D2 or D3) are animal liver, fatty fish (e.g.,
salmon, halibut, cod), egg yolks, and fish oils. Because human milk is an
extremely poor source of vitamin D, breast-fed infants
require a vitamin D supplement. This contributes to the other reason to the inadequacy in the body.

On the other hand, excessively high intakes of vitamin D are associated with hypercalcemia and calcinosis.

---

References

1. Nutritional Biochemistry of the Vitamins: Vitamin D (D .A Bender 2nd Ed)
2. Modern Nutrition in Health and Disease 11thed Ross et al.

Comment: Disagree. Human milk is low in vitamin d only because breast feeding mothers may be low. It's more logical to treat the mother.

Comment: @Graham I guess the good thing about this site is the requirement of references, besides as a medical personnel I have seen this often in practice, many babies are given vitamin D (400UI) because of this condition.

Comment: @GrahamChiu if you still doubt, perhaps this gives a better idea: [Vitamin D Supplementation](https://www.cdc.gov/breastfeeding/recommendations/vitamin_d.htm)

Comment: https://kellymom.com/nutrition/vitamins/vitamin-d-and-breastfeeding/ http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/early/2015/09/22/peds.2015-1669

Comment: Your first comment is based on assumption which makes your last comment contradictory. Either way breast milk is still not a good source of vitamin D, therefore supplemention is necessary.

Comment: There are specific mechanisms that pull vitamin D from the maternal store of Vitamin D ( not free Vitamin D ) bound to vitamin D binding protein which allows for Vitamin D to appear in breast milk.  However, if the mother is deficient, then that doesn't work!  Also, mothers fail to follow guidelines on infant supplementation so that only 15% of breast feeding infants receive the drops.  It's more logical to treat the breast feeding mother.